# OWL reasonnement, how to infer relative to two different classes?

Tags: jena, owl, inference, reasoning

i am working about inferences. I am using Jena OWL reasoner.

I have two kind of idividuals, Servers and Applications. Servers can host Applications, the object property responsible to make the link is "data:heberge". I would locate the applications that are hosted on servers.

Servers are written like this:

```
<owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="&data;applications-271018">
                <rdf:type rdf:resource="&data;applications"/>
                <data:app-nivhie rdf:datatype="&xsd;string">3</data:app-nivhie>
                <data:eap-cod rdf:datatype="&xsd;string">MTSSBR</data:eap-cod>
                <data:eap-lib rdf:datatype="&xsd;string">GMAO</data:eap-lib>
                <data:eap-nom rdf:datatype="&xsd;string">Mantis Saint Brice</data:eap-nom>
                <data:eap-rspetu rdf:datatype="&xsd;string">ET PATRIM</data:eap-rspetu>
                <data:eap-rspprd rdf:datatype="&xsd;string">PF HEBERGEMENT</data:eap-spprd>
                <data:eap-typ rdf:datatype="&xsd;string">Progiciel</data:eap-typ>
                <data:eap-typobj rdf:datatype="&xsd;string">Application</data:eap-typobj>
</owl:NamedIndividual>
```

Applications are this:

```
<owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="&data;serveur-280726">
                <rdf:type rdf:resource="&data;serveur"/>
                <data:ast rdf:datatype="&xsd;string">3074</data:ast>
                <data:ast-designation rdf:datatype="&xsd;string">WIT</data:ast-designation>
                <data:host rdf:datatype="&xsd;string">Witt International</data:host>
                <data:identifiantrdf:datatype="&xsd;string">DEVDWITZB1</data:identifiant>
                <data:serv-env rdf:datatype="&xsd;string">DVP Développement</data:serv-env>
                <data:state rdf:datatype="&xsd;string">Serveur</data:state>
                <data:status rdf:datatype="&xsd;string">En service</data:status>
                <data:svr-numero-serie rdf:datatype="&xsd;string">-</data:svr-numero-serie>
                <data:vm rdf:datatype="&xsd;string">Machine virtuelle</data:vm>
</owl:NamedIndividual>
```

I try the the following code, but it dont work correctly:

```
<owl:Class rdf:about="&data;estInstallée">
    <owl:equivalentClass>
        <owl:Class>
            <owl:equivalentClass>
                <owl:Restriction>
                    <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="&data;heberge"/>
                    <owl:someValuesFrom rdf:resource="&data;applications"/>
                </owl:Restriction>
            <owl:Class rdf:about="&data;serveur"/>
            </owl:equivalentClass>
        </owl:Class>
    <owl:Class rdf:about="&data;applications"/>
    </owl:equivalentClass>
</owl:Class>
```

please do you have idea?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, this was also posted on the protege-user mailing list.  While both SO and the mailing list are valid places to look for support, it probably makes sense to try one at a time, unless you'll come and post the answer from the mailing list here.  Otherwise we end up with unanswered questions on Stack Overflow. :(

Comment: The indentation in the last snippet is rather strange.  Was this generated by hand?